# Removed apt-get from Ubuntu; how to recover?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, system-recovery

Well my fingers did manage to do `sudo apt-get remove libstdc++6` and write, `yes`. That removed a lot of system files. Is there any way to bring it up working again? I have connected to terminal, and `wget` is working fine. I managed to `ctrl+C` when figured out what was happening.

I think the main thing would be to get `apt-get`, but how?

Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric x64bit

Comment: Doesn't the Ubuntu CD have a "repair system" feature?

Comment: Haha, shame man. I agree with @MrLister, maybe the Ubuntu CD has something to repair all broken / missing files on your system.

Answer (score 9):

You can still install any package via `dpkg -i package.deb` after downloading it with `wget` from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com). And even if `dpkg` is broken, you can unpack the *.deb* with `ar` and then copy the contents with `cp` manually.

Comment: I would also mention to run as much of the preinst and postinst as possible.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS If you can get `apt-get` working, it has `--reinstall` - that would handle the rest, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would start with downloading the package of apt-get ( if possible trough the ubuntu repository and running

```
dpkg -i <package-name>
```

If dpkg is not available next step would be building it from source. 
Same thing for all the unmet dependancies you might encounter.